# SQL: Union with subqueries

Tags: postgresql

My structure is like this

table1
key 
value
date

table2
key
value
date

table3
key 
value
date

I would like to have a sql query which returns distinct all keys
and the sum of all values for each key from all 3 tables.

My try has been

> Select key=
>   (select table1.key from table1 where date = '2017-05-30' 
>   union 
> select table2.key from table2 where date = '2017-05-30' union
>  select
>   table3.key from table3 where date = '2017-05-30'), 
> (select sum(value)
>   from table1 where table1.key = key and date = '2017-05-30' ) + 
> select
>   (sum(value) from table2 where table2.key = key and date =
>   '2017-05-30') + 
> select (sum(value) from table3 where table3.key=key
>   and date = '2017-05-30') 
> from table1, table2, table3

Comment: please format query - it is barely readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could combine the 3 tables into a temporary table and then do what you need to do on the temporary table:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE temp1 AS
select key, value, date from table1
union all
select key, value, date from table2
union all
select key, value, date from table3
```